# Удаление лишних дефисов из номеров телефонов в выгрузке 1С

Tags: 1с

в Базе данных 1С имеем список контрагентов, информация контрагента - ФИО и номер телефона. Задача - в выгрузке в текстовый файл убрать из номеров телефонов дефисы, т.е. +7-901-222-22-22 преобразовать в +79012222222. Понимаю, что нужно как-то использовать СтрЗаменить, но не понимаю, как это использовать в текущем виде :

```
Процедура ВыгрузкаКонтрагентов()

ЗаписьЖурналаРегистрации("ВыгрузкаКонтрагентов", УровеньЖурналаРегистрации.Информация, , , "Начало выполнения");

Попытка

    ТекстДок = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент;

            Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст =
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   Контрагенты.Ссылка,
    |   Контрагенты.Наименование
    |ИЗ
    |   Справочник.Контрагенты КАК Контрагенты
    |ГДЕ
    |   Не Контрагенты.ПометкаУдаления";

    Выборка = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();

    Пока Выборка.Следующий() Цикл

        Телефон = "";

        СрокаКИ = Выборка.Ссылка.КонтактнаяИнформация.Найти(Справочники.ВидыКонтактнойИнформации.ТелефонКонтрагента, "Вид");

        Если Не СрокаКИ = Неопределено Тогда

            Телефон = СрокаКИ.Представление;

        КонецЕсли;

        ТекстДок.ДобавитьСтроку(Выборка.Наименование + ";"+Телефон+";");

    КонецЦикла;

    ТекстДок.Записать("C:\contacts\contacts.csv");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед строкой

```
ТекстДок.ДобавитьСтроку(Выборка.Наименование + ";"+Телефон+";");
```

поставьте

```
Телефон = СтрЗаменить(Телефон,"-","");
```

Comment: В файле на выходе в таком случае почему-то убираются и плюсы, т.е. номера телефонов становятся в формате не +7ххх... , а в 7ххх 
Странно, читаю документацию по СтрЗаменить, и оно должно работать именно так как вы и написали

Comment: Добавьте вывод информации из Телефон на экран пользователю до преобразования `Телефон = СтрЗаменить(Телефон,"-","");` и посмотрите присутствуют ли там плюсы. А функция действительно не должна удалять плюс.

Comment: Проблема решилась, похоже, это был косяк экселя (баг в отображении)